# Excel function to change ID numbers based on list of old/new ID's

Tags: excel, function

I have a list of id numbers for people that now have to have a new id. Shown below, in excel, I put the old id's and the new id's into the sheet next to each other. So old ID: 111 actually is ID: 123 and so on. I have a list of id's that need to be changed (Change This ID) and I would like the new changed ID to go into the result column. So,  Instead of manually going through and changing them, is there a way to have a function do this for me? It would look at what is in the "Change This ID" column and see 444, then would go to the "Old ID" column and find 444, then go the the "New ID" column in the same row and find 101, then put that into the "Result ID" column. Then would go to the next line and do 333 and so on.

```
Old ID | New Id | Change This Id| Result Id| Name | Address |
-------------------------------------------
111    | 123    | 444           | 101      |
222    | 456    | 333           | 789      | 
333    | 789    | 111           | 123      |
444    | 101    | ...           | ...      |
555    | 334    | ...           | ...      |
...    | ...    |
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `VLOOKUP` function and write a formula to look up the `New ID` for the Id's that need to be changed.

```
    A      | B      | C             | D        | E    | F       |
 1  Old ID | New Id | Change This Id| Result Id| Name | Address |
    -------------------------------------------------------------
 2  111    | 123    | 444           | 101      |
 3  222    | 456    | 333           | 789      | 
 4  333    | 789    | 111           | 123      |
 5  444    | 101    | ...           | ...      |
 6  555    | 334    | ...           | ...      |
    ...    | ...    |
```

Therefore, for the above data set, with the Row Numbers (1, 2, etc.) and the Column Names (A, B, etc.), you can write a formula in cell D1 as follows:

`=VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,FALSE)`

There are probably some Id's that did not change. To avoid getting an error for these Id's and just copy them over, you can wrap the VLOOKUP formula inside the IFERROR function (thanks to @Jeeped for the idea, see comments below), as follows:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2, A:B, 2, FALSE), C2)`

Once you have the formula working in cell D1, you can use the Auto Fill feature to populate all the new Id's in Column D.

**References**:

[VLOOKUP function on Microsoft Office Reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

[IFERROR function on Microsoft Office Reference](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/IFERROR-function-C526FD07-CAEB-47B8-8BB6-63F3E417F611)

[Auto fill on Microsoft Office Reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db)

Comment: I was thinking that it may be a bit better to use wrap the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) in an [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) that can return the original if the new one cannot be located. e.g. `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2, A:B, 2, FALSE), C2)`

Comment: @Jeeped Really good idea to avoid a two-step process for merging the Id's that did not change. I will include it in my answer.

Comment: @JosephB Thank you for the reply, i will try this tomorrow and accept the answer when it works